# Creating vectors between specific values in a dataset with R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a quite special case with a dataset and what I want to do with it.To make it comprehensive I have to give a brief description of the background:

I have a sensor producing data, which needs maintenance every-now-and-then. Between every maintenance the data produced has a decreasing trend which I want to get rid of, and since maintenance is carried out quite often, I want to automate this procedure. 
The sensor is turned off when carrying out maintenance but the telemetry system still produces readings marked with " * ". Therefore the subsets of data to be detrended can be easily spotted between batches of "*" readings.
I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to create a vector (on which I can then carry out a detrending procedure) with this data by selecting the desired values by looping through the data using conditional statements. To begin selecting the values I used to following statement:

```
if((tryp[i-2,2]="*")&(tryp[i-1,2]="*")&(tryp[i,2]!="*"))
```

and to finish the selection (exit the loop):

```
if((tryp[i-2,2]!="*")&(tryp[i-1,2]!="*")&(tryp[i,2]="*"))
```

However, this last statement gives an error of "argument is of length zero" and the first statement doesn't seem to be working properly either.

[This is how the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L1Z4.jpg)

So for example, one subset of data that I would like to select for de-trending is between data points 9686 and 9690. Obviously this is very small subset, but it shows well what I am trying to communicate.

I would really appreciate if someone could let me know about an elegant way of doing this, including anything way different from what I was trying to do originally.

Many thanks!

Comment: For comparison, you should use `==`. `=` is for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:10], b = c('+','*','*', '+', '*', '*', '+', '+', '*', '*'))
my_df %>% filter(b != '*')
```

Suppose the '+'-signs are your data points, you can easily get rid of the '*'-signs with filtering the rows which does not contain it.

And of course a solution without the `dplyr`-package:

```
my_df[which(my_df$b!='*'),]
```